# Get Post thumbnail without width/height attribute

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am wondering if there is an easier/more efficient way to print a post thumbnail without the width/height attributes.

I like to control my image sizes with CSS, so I can do things like: `width: 30%` and then let the height adjust automatically based on the aspect ratio of the image.

I've been looking through the codex for hours, and every function I can find seems to print both a width and a height attribute, which breaks my intended CSS. The CSS property overrides the width defined on the image, but the height is unchanged --[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6bd06pv/).

I can get around this with the following:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
    get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail'
);

if ($image) {
    echo "<img src='" . $image[0] . "' />";

}
```

Ultimately, I've written my own function to achieve this in a way that (sort of) mimics what the_post_thumbnail does:

```
function oct_getPostThumbnail($postId = null, $attributes = array()) {

    $postId = ( null === $postId ) ? get_the_ID() : $postId;
    $thumbnailId = get_thumbnail_id( $postId );

    if ( $thumbnailId ) {

        $defaultAttributes = array(
            'id' => 'postThumbnail-' . $thumbnailId,
            'class' => 'postThumbnail',
            'width' => null,
            'height' => null,
            'alt' => get_the_title($postId) . " thumbnail image"
        );


        $attributes = array_merge($defaultAttributes, $attributes);
        /* This works, but it feels wrong. Is there a better way to default values
            not passed into the function? */

        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnailId, 'single-post-thumbnail');

        if ($image) {
            $src = $image[0];
            $id = $attributes['id'];
            $class = $attributes['class'];
            $width = $attributes['width'];
            $height = $attributes['height'];
            $alt = $attributes['alt'];

            $html = "<img src='$src'";
                if (!empty($id)) {
                    $html = $html . " id ='$id' ";
                }

                if (!empty($class)) {
                    $html = $html . " class='$class' ";
                }

                if (!empty($width)) {
                    $html = $html . " width='$width' ";
                }

                if (!empty($height)) {
                    $html = $html . " height='$height' ";
                }

                if (!empty($alt)) {
                    $html = $html . " alt='$alt' ";
                }
            $html = $html . " />";

            echo $html;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This should accomplish what I want it to, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it. There are a few points in this function that feel overly complicated, but I'm not 100% sure how to streamline it.

Comment: see if it helps setting your css height to auto.

Comment: as @gdaniel said, setting `height` to `auto` fix that, actually http://jsfiddle.net/c3Ltt4bh/1/

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. I've been so consumed with learning all the WordPress functions that I never thought to play with the CSS. That solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: @gmazzap I'll need to play around a bit, but at a glance, it looks like that `!important` isn't necessary. Just `height: auto;` did the trick.